# .Net Core DI Does Not Work For Me And Throws Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am new to .net core and need your help. Below is my implementation that does not work

Main.cs

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging()
            .AddTransient<ICustomLogger, TextWriterLogger>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        StartAsyncTest(args);
    }

    public async static void StartAsyncTest(string[] args)
    {

        HttpAsyncTest.SetupCommand dto = new HttpAsyncTest.SetupCommand();
        HttpAsyncTest.ExecuteCommand executeCommand = new HttpAsyncTest.ExecuteCommand();
        var test = executeCommand.ExecuteAsync(new HttpAsyncTest(dto));
        await test;
    }
```

My Execute Command is in a different .Net Core Class Library called AsyncTest.Domain

```
public partial class HttpAsyncTest : IValidEntity, IBuisnessEntity
{
    public HttpAsyncTest(SetupCommand dto)
    {
        HttpRequestContainers = new List<HttpAsyncRequestContainer>();
        this.Setup(dto);
    }

    private ICustomLogger _logger;
    public HttpAsyncTest(ICustomLogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    async public Task ExecuteAsync(ExecuteCommand dto)
    {
         _logger.Log // throws null reference exception 
    }
}
```

The ILogger interface is in the domain class library and its implementation is in the infrastructure library and the domain does not reference the infrastructure one as per the DDD principles.

What am I doing wrong above and how do I fix the null reference exception.

Sorry, I am new to the .net core and .net core DI and need your guidance.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest reading more on dependency injection and DI containers. Your question shows a clear lack of understanding on how it works. You cannot new up instances yourself and expect that the container would magically work like that.

Comment: For any one visiting this question later, the below article is a great one to start with 
https://auth0.com/blog/dependency-injection-in-dotnet-core/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't use DI Container to create the instance, the `_logger` field will point `NULL` in `HttpAsyncTest` object, and you didn't assign `ICustomLogger` field from your code.

```
public partial class HttpAsyncTest : IValidEntity, IBuisnessEntity
{
    public HttpAsyncTest(SetupCommand dto,ICustomLogger logger)
    {
        HttpRequestContainers = new List<HttpAsyncRequestContainer>();
        _logger = logger;
        this.Setup(dto);
    }

    private ICustomLogger _logger;

    async public Task ExecuteAsync(ExecuteCommand dto)
    {
         _logger.Log;
    }
}
```

In `Main` method, you can call by `serviceProvider` DI Container object which you can get `HttpAsyncTest` object from this Container that will create an object as you register.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddLogging()
        .AddTransient<ICustomLogger, TextWriterLogger>()
        .AddTransient<SetupCommand>()
        .AddTransient<HttpAsyncTest>() 
        .BuildServiceProvider();
}

public async static void StartAsyncTest(ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{

    HttpAsyncTest.ExecuteCommand executeCommand = new HttpAsyncTest.ExecuteCommand();
    var test = executeCommand.ExecuteAsync(serviceProvider.GetService<HttpAsyncTest>());
    await test;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I do not want the SetupCommand to be injected as I want to provide an instantiated object, is there anyway?

Comment: @MoHaidar You can try passing `SetupCommand ` by the method instead of using a constructor.

Comment: Thanks, that is going to break my design as I am deliberately forcing the instantiation through the constructor to avoid inserting empty objects to the DB so the developers who are going to use it provides the bear minimum data.  Anyway thanks for your help, I am reading more about .Net core IOC and see if this is the right choice.

Comment: And I am accepting your answer as it put me on the way to a proper understanding of the .NET Core IOC